# Range of the function $f(x) = x + \frac1x$

Tags: calculus, functions

I tried to find the range of $f(x)$ by finding its maxima and minima.
However, the results were surprising

$f'(x)$ came out to be $1 - \dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

Equating it to zero, I got the values of $x$ as $1$ and $-1$.

Now $f''(x)$ came out to be $\dfrac{2}{x^3}$.

Now $f''(1)$ would be $2 > 0$.

Hence at $x = 1$, the function would be minimum with value $f(1)$, which is equal to $2$.

Hence at $x = -1$, the function would be maximum with value $f(-1)$, which is equal to $-2$.

How would this be possible, the minimum being $2$ and the maximum bring $-2$?

I got a different result when I used the inequality $A.M. \ge G.M.$.

I got $x \ge 2$.

This has been confusing me for a while.  Please help by providing a proper explanation.

It would be appreciated if the graph of $f(x)$ would be provided.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your function is not defined at $0$.

Comment: Hi :) For $x>0$ we have $f(x) \geq 2$ and for $x<0$ we have $f(x)\leq -2$ because $-f(x) =f(-x) \geq 2$.

Comment: Enter the function $x + 1/x$ in https://www.desmos.com and you'll the how the function looks. Also the reasoning you did is correct, but only identifies local maxima and minima - hence the value at a maximum can be smaller than the value at a minimum.

Comment: AM-GM cannot be applied on negative numbers

Comment: But how can the value of the minima be greater than the value of the maxima ?

Comment: The graph suggests that the extreme values of y = f(x) would tend to infinity and - infinity

Comment: In such a case why does the double derivative give a different answer ?

Comment: Your "minimum" is valid only on $(0,\infty)$, since the function is continuous there and tends to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow0^+$ and as $x\rightarrow\infty$. You cannot conclude it is a global minimum as $f$ is not continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=x+\frac{1}{x}$. Now, $x^2+1-xy=0$. Now, if $y$ is in the range of the function, then this quadratic will have at least one real root. $y^2-4 \geq 0$ or $y\in (-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*
Here is what it looks like.

[image: A]

It is a hyperbola, with asymptotes $x=0$ and $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need derivative, let consider $x>0$ then by AM-GM or by rearrangement inequality, as already noticed

$$f(x)=x+\frac1x \ge 2$$

with equality for $x=\frac1x$ that is $x=1$.

Moreover we have also that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=\infty$$

Then observe that

$$f(-x)=-x+\frac1{-x}=-\left(x+\frac1x\right)=-f(x)$$

therefore the function is odd with range $(-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)$.